# Creating a TCP connection between 2 computers without a server

Tags: tcp, connection, p2p, multicast

- 2 computers are in different subnets.
- Both are Windows machines.
- There are 2-5 IGMP-ready routers between them.
- They can connect each other over multicast protocol (they have joined the same multicast group and they know about each other's existance).

How to establish a reliable TCP connection between them without any public server?

Programming language: C++, WinAPI

*(I need a TCP connection to send some big critical data, which I can not entrust to UDP)*

Comment: @bmargulies, how to specify "IP:port"? They are in different subnets, maybe behind 5 routers. There are could be different IP-classes in different subnets. If I'll simply specify an IP of other subnet, the connection will be established?

Comment: the simple answer is 'yes'. That's what the routing protocols are for. See my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't specified a programming language, so this whole question may be off-topic.

Subnets are not the problem. Routability is the problem. Either there is routing set up or there isn't. If they are, for example, both behind NAT boxes, then you're at the mercy of the configuration of the nat boxes. If they are merely on two different subnets of a routed network, it's the job of the network admin to have set up routing. So, each has an IP address, and either can address the other.

On one machine, you are going to create a socket, bind it to some port of your choice, and listen. On the other, you will connect to the first machine's IP + the selected port.

**edit**

I'm going to try again, but I feel like there's a giant conceptual gap here.

Once upon a time, the TCP/IP was invented. In the original conception, every item on the network has an IPV4 address, and every machine could reach every other machine, via routing, except for machines in the 'private' address space (10.x, etc).

In the very early days, the only 'subnets' were 'class A, class B, class C'. Later the idea of subdividing a network via bitmasks was added. The concept of 'subnet' is just a way of describing a piece of network in which all the hosts can deliver packets to each other by one hop over some transport or another. In a properly configured network, this is only of concern to operating system drivers. Ordinary programs just address packets over the network and they arrive.

The implementation of this connectivity was always via routing protocol. If you have a (physical) ethernet A over here, and a (physical) ethernet B over there, connected by some sort of point-to-point link, the machines on A need to know where to send packets for B. Or, to be exact, they need to know where to send 'not-A' packets, and whatever they send them needs to know where to send 'B' packets. In simple cases, this is arranged via explicit configuration: routing rules stuffed into router boxes or even computers with multiple physical interfaces. In more complex cases, routing boxes intercommunicate via protocols like EGP or BGP or IGMP to learn the network topology.

If you use the Windows 'route' command, you will see the 'default route' that the system uses to send packets that need to leave the local subnet. It is generally the address of the router box responsible for moving information from the local subnet to everywhere else.

The whole goal of this routing is to arrange that a packet sent from a.b.c.d to e.f.g.h will get there. TCP is no different than UDP, except that you can't get there by multicast or broadcast: you need to know the exact address of your correspondent.

DNS was invented to allow hosts to learn each other's IP addresses without having human being send them around in email messages.

All this stops working when people start using NAT and firewalls to turn off routing. The whole idea of NAT is that the computers behind the NAT box are *not* addressable at all. They all appear to have one IP address. They can send stuff out, but they can only receive stuff if the NAT box has gone to extra trouble to map them a port.

From your original message, I sort of doubt that NAT is in use here. I just don't understand your comment 'I don't have access to the network.' You say that you've sent UDP packets here and there. So how did you do that? What addresses did you use?

Comment: So, active IGMP connections will not give any help in this task?

Comment: IGMP is one of the tools used to establish routability, so it's cause for optimism. What are the IP addresses of the two machines? What do you see if you use the 'traceroute' command from one to the other?

Comment: I still don't have an access to that network, therefore I have to prepare some generalized method of doing it. You mean there is no generalized method and everything depends on current network configuration? Which configuration is preferred then?

Comment: Thank a lot for the explanation! I'm sorry for my stupidity, my previous comment means that I cannot test my software in that multi-router network right now, but I'll do it later. The UDP multicast worked fine there before, but I wasn't sure that routers will do the same job with TCP connection.